# 2D Array with different dataypes in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

[2d array with two different datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731493/2d-array-with-two-different-datatypes)
(Extending the same for C)

Is there a provision of having a 2D array in C where it can have the list of an id (which is a number) in 1st column and a pointer to a structure instance in 2nd column, instances as:

```
Array[][2] = {{1,&a3}, {3,&b1}, {8,&b2}}
```

where a1, a2, a3, and b1, b2, b3 are the instances of structures A and B respectively.

Comment: An array of structs?

Comment: you can try with `void*`.

Comment: The fist column is not pointer its an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an array in C by definition can't hold values of different types, you should try it out with an **array of structures** instead.